# Where this CSS menu fails?

Tags: php, css, html

here comes the HTML:

```
<ul id="plugins_fullMenu">
<li><a href="/">&nbsp;Főoldal&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="introduce">&nbsp;Bemutatkozás&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="products">&nbsp;Termékek&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="NYETT">&nbsp;Kategóriák&nbsp;</a>
<ul class="plugins_fullMenu first">
<li><a href="asdasdsada">&nbsp;kateg1&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="bxcvxcvxcv">&nbsp;kateg2&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="NYETT">&nbsp;prognyelv&nbsp;</a>
<ul class="plugins_fullMenu ">
<li><a href="3.1">&nbsp;C#&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="3.2">&nbsp;C&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="3.3">&nbsp;C++&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="links">&nbsp;Linkek&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="NYETT">&nbsp;Admin felület&nbsp;</a>
<ul class="plugins_fullMenu">
<li><a href="1">&nbsp;a&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="2">&nbsp;b&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="veg">&nbsp;veg&nbsp;</a></li></ul>
```

and the CSS:

```
#plugins_fullMenu, .plugins_fullMenu, #plugins_fullMenu .plugins_fullMenu li
{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 display: table;
}
#plugins_fullMenu li
{
 float:left;
 display: inline;
 cursor:pointer;
 list-style:none;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border:1px #000 solid;
 position:relative;
}
#plugins_fullMenu li ul.first
{
 left:-1px; top:100%;
 background-color: red;
}

li, li a
{
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
#plugins_fullMenu .plugins_fullMenu li
{
 width:100%;
/* text-indent:10px;
 line-height:30px;
 margin-right:10px;*/
 border-top:1px #000 solid;
 border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
 border-left:none;
 border-right:none;
 background:red;
}
#plugins_fullMenu li a
{
 display:block;
 width:inherit;
 height:inherit;
}

ul.plugins_fullMenu
{
 display:none;
}
#plugins_fullMenu li:hover > a, #plugins_fullMenu li:hover
{
 color:#fff;
 background:green;
}
li:hover > .plugins_fullMenu
{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 width:auto;
 top:-1px;
 left:50%;
 z-index:1000;
 border:1px #000 solid;
}
li:hover
{
 position:relative;
 z-index:2000;
}
```

now the problem is the two submenu of "admin felület" overlaps it. It should not, whats wrong?

Comment: sorry for this "stack overflow" effect, it didnt let me open the topic like that!

Comment: Don't just paste your code and expect someone to fix it. Please show us what your problem really is. The best way is to provide a real example using jsfiddle.net or any other similar platform.

Comment: it's bacuase it's class is only `plugins_fullMenu` while the other one is `plugins_fullMenu first`

Comment: aha. Ok, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/SLfHW/ and you can see the two submenus of "admin felület" is higher than it should

Comment: Elen youre da man! Cant you post it as "post" so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok. as suggested

your fist submenu class is `plugins_fullMenu first` while the next one is only `plugins_fullMenu`